Tail light cluster upgrade (Solved)
First post, so be kind!
I have upgraded my 2009 VW Phaeton tail lights to the facelift cluster.  Mounting and electrical connections are identical.  The tail lights, brake lights and fog lights all work as advertised.  I have modified the reverse lights (which were traditional bulb) to the facelift LED with resistors, and they are fine.  My issue is with the indicators.
The old cluster was 28 LEDs per side, the new cluster 13 LEDs. Although initially working fine, after a seemingly arbitrary, but short time, the controller shuts the rear indicators off, giving a bulb warning on the dash.  Suspecting a resistance error between the clusters, I again wired in resistors.  This has solved the cancelling by the controller, and seems to have solved the problem until the engine is running, when the indicators now work, but the rear indicator cluster  is flickering fast when illuminated.  I have tried 50W 8 ohm and 25 ohm resistors, with identical results.  Would an intelligent decoder possible solve the flickering, or is there a more fundamental problem here?  Thank you in advance!

OK, solved this in case anyone has a similar problem.  The HID dual core decoders worked brilliantly.  All lights now work as advertised.
